# converting xml file to html

Tags: c#, xml

i have a task to do. i need to convert xml to html file. i check the tag and then write the html file with the tag based from the xml file.
 Like if i found `<BookHeader>` i write `<h1>` in the html file.

i have this

layout of xml

```
<BookHeader>
    <AuthorGroup>
      <Author >
        <AuthorName >
          <GivenName>Juanita</GivenName>
          <FamilyName>Gomez</FamilyName>
        </AuthorName>
        <Contact>
          <Email>Juanita@gmail.com</Email>
        </Contact>
      </Author>

    </AuthorGroup>
  </BookHeader>

  <ChapterInfo >
      <ChapterID>1</ChapterID>
      <ChapterNumber>Chapter 1</ChapterNumber>

      <ChapterTitle Language="En">Just some Title</ChapterTitle>


      <ChapterHistory>
        <RegistrationDate>
          <Year>2020</Year>
          <Month>8</Month>
          <Day>18</Day>
        </RegistrationDate>
      </ChapterHistory>

    </ChapterInfo>
```

i have this code in c#

i read the xml element one by one. so far the code below does is print all elements and its content

but what i want to do is if the element name is `<ChapterHistory>` the program will not read the content of the tag up to its closing tag

so the program will not read the tag

```
<RegistrationDate>
              <Year>2020</Year>
              <Month>8</Month>
              <Day>18</Day>
            </RegistrationDate>
```

how can i do this? thank you so much. i have a hard time doing this

```
XmlReader rdr = XmlReader.Create(new System.IO.StringReader(myString));

            while (rdr.Read())
            {

                switch (rdr.NodeType)
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element:
                        Console.WriteLine("<" + rdr.Name + ">");

                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.Text:
                        Console.WriteLine(rdr.Value);

                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                        Console.WriteLine("...");
                        break;
                }
                count++;

            }
```

Comment: I would use `xslt` instead of manually parsing the file. Or when you really need logic, not parse xml but deserialize it, or query it with `xpath`.

Comment: but i dont have xslt file sir. the user want is read the file and the output is html file. the input is xml

Comment: What do you mean "the program should not read the content of the tag up to its closing tag"? I think this is impossible if you want to continue reading anything behind it at all.  OTOH, your xml is not valid at all as it has two top level nodes `BookHeader` and `ChapterInfo`, so we assume that there is something "around it" to make it valid. Instead of "not reading" it you should put a variable in your code that indicates that you do not want to "output" the corresponding HTML code for that section.

Comment: You could write it yourself. Or generate XSD with code-behind classes, or just query with the `xpath` instead of manually parsing elements.

Comment: ill try the xslt suggestion. but does it output html? i need html output. in order to create epub. ill start to read what is xslt now. thanks

Comment: Show us desired HTML output.

Answer (score 1):

NB. I don't know C# so I can only try to explain in plain language.

You could simply map the values, e.g. if rdr.Name is `BookHeader` then write `<h1>` etc.pp. If you have access to the `rdr.Name`  in the `EndElement` case you can simply close the same mapped value like `</h1>`. Otherwise you'd have to keep track of the open elements yourself and close the innermost.

About the problem to skip some of the xml structure see my comment to the question.

Note that I agree with some other commentators that this problem generally is more suited for an XSLT solution.