# how to get all nodename using xpath

Tags: c#, xpath

Good day,

what im trying to do in general is convert the xml to xhtml. i need the xhtml in order to create an epub

the input is xml. the user want is the insert the xml in the program and the output is xhtml file. with the proper layout.

so what im trying to do in the code below is checking the nodename. in order for the program to know what html tag is to use.

example in the xml file there is a Title element. so in my program. it will write `<h1>` when the node is Title.

thank you. i hope my question is clear.

i have this sample xml from microsoft

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
   <!-- This file represents a fragment of a book store inventory database -->
   <bookstore>
     <book genre="autobiography">
       <title>The Autobiography of Benjamin Franklin</title>
       <author>
         <first-name>Benjamin</first-name>
         <last-name>Franklin</last-name>
       </author>
       <price>8.99</price>
     </book>
     <book genre="novel">
       <title>The Confidence Man</title>
       <author>
         <first-name>Herman</first-name>
         <last-name>Melville</last-name>
       </author>
       <price>11.99</price>
     </book>
     <book genre="philosophy">
       <title>The Gorgias</title>
       <author>
         <name>Plato</name>
       </author>
       <price>9.99</price>
     </book>
   </bookstore>
```

what i want to do is get the all the node name in the loop

```
strExpression = "/bookstore";

            // Select the node and place the results in an iterator.
            NodeIter = nav.Select(strExpression);


            //Iterate through the results showing the element value.
            while (NodeIter.MoveNext())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Book Title: " + NodeIter.Current.Value);
            };
```

Comment: how is this related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37830550/converting-xml-file-to-html#comment63123347_37830550 ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to get *all* node names for a given `Xml` you could simply do this.

I prefer using `Linq` to `Xml`.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);

var nodenames = doc.Descendants()     // Read all descendants
       .Select(x=>x.Name.LocalName)   // Look for node name.
       .ToList();
```

Now you could access elements by looping through `nodenames`.

foreach(var name in nodenames)
{
    Console.WriteLine(name); //Access name here.
}

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iva7bQ)

Comment: how do i use that? i copied the code and it say 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' does not contain a definition for 'Dump' and no extension method 'Dump'

Comment: Don't use `Dump` in actual code,use simple foreach loop to loop through each node.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you use `XPathNavigator`. Here is the code demonstrating its use

```
var doc = new XPathDocument("test.xml");
var nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
var iter = nav.Select("//*");

while (iter.MoveNext())
{
    Console.WriteLine(iter.Current.LocalName);
}
```

The `//*` xpath expression retrieves all descendants nodes.